# Pandas sum of sum of groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sum

I'm trying to groupby a column in pandas and then sum the groupby.

Here is an example df and my expected output:

```
d = {'a':[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2], 'b': [3, 4, 5, 6, 7,8,9] }
data = pd.DataFrame(data = d)


# should return sum of sum of groups
# correct output would be 42
```

I know that I can return the sum of groups by using:

```
data.groupby('a')['b'].transform(sum)

# which returns

0    18
1    18
2    18
3    18
4    24
5    24
6    24
Name: b, dtype: int64
```

However, I'm not sure how to get the sum of the sum of groups.
i.e.

```
# sum of groupby
# group 1: 18
# group 2: 24
# sum of sum of groupby
# 18 + 24 = 42
```

Comment: why not summing up all the elements from column b by `data['b'].sum()`??

Comment: Yes.. yes it would.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `agg` in place of `transform`.

```
res = data.groupby('a')['b'].agg(sum).sum()
```

---

**res:**

```
42
```

---

```
data.groupby('a')['b'].agg(sum)
```

will give you

```
a
1    18
2    24
Name: b, dtype: int64
```